# Project line segment onto a vertical line

Tags: mathematics

If I had a vertical line (which its *x* is 0) and 2 vectors which connected together to form a line segment, would it be possible to "project" the line segment onto the vertical line?

Eg.
[image]

If all I had was *Vector 1* and *Vector 2*, would it be find where *Vector 3* is along the vertical line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If vector1 is `(x1, y1)`, vec2 is `(x2, y2)` and vec3 is  `(x3, y3)`, and the vertical line has the equation `x = c`, then

```
x3 = c
y3 = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) * (c - x1) + y1
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works! I've tried using slope before but looks like I did it wrong. :-)